Understanding the dimension d in packageX LoopRefine
I'm trying to use Mathematica PackageX to compute the QED electron mass correction. Feyncalc with packageX helper also works and gives the same result. However, I don't understand the result.
The problem happens after I input the correct diagram. Since PackageX has an explicit example of QED electron mass, I can cross check with it. LoopIntegrate gives the correct PaVe integrals. By checking those integrals, I found they indeed agree with textbook, e.g. Schwartz eq 18.12.
My code (since PackageX requires to use subscriptions which is not supported here, let me just give screenshot)

Output:

The problem is if I do the LoopRefine directly, the result is different from if I replace d by 4 and then do the loopRefine just for the integrals. However, the latter one gives the correct result as the textbook, e.g. Schwartz 18.65, which says the finite part is 5 + 3 log(\mu/m).

Screenshot:

So I'm pretty confused here. Why taking d->4 lead to different result? And, I suppose that directly running LoopRefine should be the best way but the result is different from the textbook. Then which one should I trust?

First a reminder to other readers : questions about Mathematica Packages are on-topic. To the OP, @IsaacWang, is that 10 year old package still maintained and compatible with new Mathematica Versions? It will be hard for people to reproduce your problem if they don't have already that package installed and you don't offer details on how you are installing it, which version, and on what Mathematica Version are you trying to use it. Packages in general may be in-topic, but I'm struggling with the idea of obsolete packages being on-topic.

Please try to make your question of general interest as much as possible. Also, please avoid the use of Subscript for any task other than display (See here). I suggest you [edit] your question to improve it.

From briefly looking into Schwartz, I think that he is using $d = 4- \varepsilon$ (cf. App B.3), while Package-X has $d = 4- 2\varepsilon$ hard-coded. So you cannot directly compare the finite parts without some extra measures.

@rhermans Thank you for pointing out the package problem. PackageX has version 2.0 and the last update was just less than 5 years ago. The author was still giving talks about this package after 2020 and just quit since 2022. So version problem is minor. I also installed this package pretty late (some time earlier this year).

@vsht Thank you for pointing out. I know the difference in the definition of epsilon. I originally thought that it only affects the infinite part, but if that also affects the finite part, I'd go back to review those process again by myself and the problem may appear there.

@IsaacWang Of course it affects the finite part, just compare Series[1/(D - 4) (a + ep b) /. D -> 4 - 2 ep, {ep, 0, 1}] with Series[1/(D - 4) (a + ep b) /. D -> 4 - ep, {ep, 0, 1}].
